# MS SQL will emulate list of numbers to find missing numbers cause performance issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

have a table "Numbers" with values (numbers). Task is to find missing values.
Numbers look like this:

```
Number
------
00000
00001
00002
00005
```

The idea to find the gaps is to have a list of all possible values join with it

```
Compare
-------
00000
00001
00002
00003
00004
```

now i can query

```
 SELECT Number FROM Compare c 
 LEFT JOIN Number n on c.Number = n.Number 
 WHERE n.Number is null
```

to fulfill this I need to fill the table "Compare" with all 100,000 values. This is possible but consuming memory and is not elegant.

For this I built a query that emulates that list and compares similar

```
SELECT '0' AS Val 
UNION SELECT '1' 
UNION SELECT '2'
UNION SELECT '3' 
UNION SELECT '4'
UNION SELECT '5' 
UNION SELECT '6'
UNION SELECT '7' 
UNION SELECT '8'
UNION SELECT '9' 
),
Zahl5Block AS (
Select C1.Val + C2.Val + C3.Val + C4.Val + C5.Val AS Block5 from C C1
FULL OUTER JOIN C C2 ON 1=1
FULL OUTER JOIN C C3 ON 1=1
FULL OUTER JOIN C C4 ON 1=1
FULL OUTER JOIN C C5 ON 1=1
)

SELECT Block5 FROM Zahl5Block z
LEFT JOIN [Numbers] n on z.Block5 = n.Number
WHERE Number is null
```

Will this cause performance / memory issues?
In real world the range of values will be bigger, I estimate 8 digits rather than 5

Comment: indeed - i am looking for strings / number with leading zeros

Comment: Why aren't you using [`GENERATE_SERIES`?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/generate-series-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) ?

Comment: Also, your `Val` values are `char(1)` and not `int` - why are you putting everything in string quotes?

Comment: Also... why are leading zeroes in numbers significant in this context? ...because they shouldn't be: leading zeroes are a _formatting concern_, which should not be done in SQL. If those values do not represent actual numbers then you need to give us more details about the **actual** problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

This will supply the missing strings

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Number] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('00000')
,('00001')
,('00002')
,('00005')

;with cte as ( 
Select * 
      ,Gap = lead(convert(int,[Number]),1) over (order by [Number]) - convert(int,[Number]) - 1
 From @YourTable
)
Select Missing = right(concat('00000',convert(int,number)+N ),5)
 From  cte A
 Join  (Select Top 10000 N=Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) From master..spt_values n1, master..spt_values n2) B
   on  N<=Gap
 Where Gap<>0
```

**Results**

```
Missing
00003
00004
```

Or if you want an ad-hoc numbers/tally table in 0.2 seconds

```
Select Top 100000 Number=right(concat('00000',-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL))),5)
 From  master..spt_values n1, master..spt_values n2
```

[image]

Comment: `master..spt_values` <-- There is no reason to continue to use this ancient practice anymore (it also won't work in modern SQL Server databases or Azure SQL that cannot reference `master` like that).

Comment: @Dai If v2022 then sure, use generate_series.  I don't thing most installs are there yet.  Futhermore, ANY table of adequate size will do.

Comment: You don't even need a table at all. you can use the usual `CROSS JOIN (VALUES` https://sqlperformance.com/2021/01/t-sql-queries/number-series-solutions-1 presto, no reads at all. There is also the option of a heavily compressed Clustered Columnstore table

Comment: @Charlieface So tired of this nonsense.  For 100K records using a CROSS JOIN VALUES is 0.803 seconds or 92% of the relattive batch.   While the from master (or any other table)  takes 0.168 seconds or 8% of the relative patch.

Comment: % of batch is meaningless, the optimizer cannot estimate the actual time. And I'm not sure what query you are trying to run, but I don't see those results https://dbfiddle.uk/P4G3kHyM Admittedly it's much of a muchness, it's more the problem of compatibility with Azure

Comment: @Charlieface My approach is twice as fast.  ...  I'm done talking about it  See image

Comment: `count(*)` ignores the actual result, as opposed to `min(rn)` which forces it to calculate it, so understandable. Like I said, the performance isn't the main issue.